# Surjectivity using a homotopy

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to solve this problem (it is not in any book, only I believe that it is true). I think that some topological concepts are needed. Do you have some suggestions?

Let $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be closed, bounded, and convex sets.

Assume $f: U \rightarrow V$ continuous.

Assume $f(\text{int} U) \subset \text{int} V$.

Assume $f: \partial U \rightarrow \partial V$ homeomorphism.

Then $f$ is surjective.

Proof.

Let $p \in \text{int} U$.

Let $H: I \times \partial V \rightarrow V$ be defined by (with $I=[0,1]$)

$H(t, y) = f\left((1-t)f^{-1}(y) + tp\right)$,

which is well-defined and continuous. Furthermore, $H(0,y) = y$ and $H(1,y) = f(p)$.

The homotopy $H$ continuously contracts the boundary $\partial V$ to $f(p)$.

Thus, for all $z \in V$, is there some $(t,y)$ such that $H(t,y) = z$?

Comment: How do you know the homotopy is surjective?

Comment: Hi @BenSteffan, if the homotopy is surjective, then the function $f$ is surjective. But, I could not prove the surjectivity of the homotopy.

Comment: This is true but the proof is quite different from the one you wrote. One uses homology or homotopy groups. You will find an argument (in the case $U=V$ is a closed ball) in most algebraic topology textbooks.

Comment: Thank you @MoisheKohan. Do you know if such an argument when $U=V=$closed ball can be extended to the case of my problem ?

Comment: Closed convex sets are homeomorphic to closed balls. This was discussed a number of times on MSE.